# content is going beyond body border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html like this :

[image]

When i click on button content is going beyond border. I have used javascript which will expand and collaps content on button click.

[image]

My css file contains following code :

```
body{border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
border: 3px solid #00FF00;border-style:outset; padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size:140%;
    }  

html,body{
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

My html file :

```
   <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('jason')">  
   <img class="butimg" src="../but.png" border="0" /></a><center>
   <div id="jason" style=" background-size: contain;display:none">
    <ul><li class="blue">Suppose that there is a unit square.   
   <li class="blue">There are four cats sitting at the four different corners of the square. </li><br>  
   <li > Each of those cats start chasing the other cat in the clockwise direction.  </li>  


    <li>The speed of the cats are same and constant and they continuously change their direction in a     manner that they are always heading straight to the other cat.</ul>
    </div><div style="visibility:hidden;height:90px">kkm</div>
```

please help.

Comment: Set div height as auto

Comment: #jason{overflow:scroll;}

Comment: @amy div height auto not working

Comment: Show us the full code inside body and the full CSS. I don't think the problem comes from what you are showing.

Comment: what d use of min-height for body and html?

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool i don't want scrolling

Comment: @Amy height:auto is not working for mobile size screen

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this CSS:

```
#jason {
     overflow: hidden;
}

#jason ul {
     display: block;
     padding: 0px;
}
```

Moreover, remove this from your stylesheet:

```
html,body{
     min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/qyj6xo6q/3/

Try something like this

```
<div class="main-block">
    <div>Here will be your first block of text</div><br>
    <div class="btn-expand">button</div><br>
    <div id="hidden-block" style="display:none">here goes your second block of text, here goes your second block of text, here goes your second block of text,</div>
</div>
```